# Remove all url paths from domain

Tags: javascript

I have a string in javascript that is a url.

Example

```
https://www.example.local/cars/bmw/12312?exp=2
```

I want to extract just the domain, no matter what the url path is. For example, all I want is

`https://www.example.local` no matter what the url paths / query params are.

How would I do this.

Comment: window.location.origin ?

Comment: `new URL('https://www.example.local/cars/bmw/12312?exp=2').origin`

Comment: or if the url you want to check is not the location of the current window `new URL("https://example.com/some/path?and=query").origin`

Answer (score -2):

Try: `window.location.origin`

```js
console.log(window.location.origin)
```